# Can't edit Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, github, create-react-app, github-pages

so I just published my create-react-app to Github Pages and everything was working fine except for the images (even though the images worked fine when I tested locally). So I tried changing things (like deleting sections of text) then publishing to Github Pages again but none of my changes will show up on the Github Pages website I set up and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

What I tried:

- Committed and pushed my changes to the repository linked with the Github Pages website
- Tried: `npm install gh-pages --save-dev` and `npm run deploy` but still no change to my website

I have tried googling but haven't found anything, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you push a change to your repository on GitHub it automatically triggers a build of your web site. You can also verify this by looking at the Commits tab in your repository, then looking at the list of commits. Those that have been built have a small green checkmark next to them.

You might also want to look in your browser console to see what errors, if any are being returned.